# Does python `str()` function call `__str__()` function of a class?

Tags: python, string, class

If I define a class with its own `__str__()` function, is `str(a)` equivalent to `a.__str__()`, where `a` is an instance of my class?

I checked the [python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str), it doesn't say explicitly that this is the case.

Comment: Why not try it out yourself?

Comment: Why don't you test it? Make a new class, and override the `__str__` method.

Comment: See the [str doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes!**

---

According to the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) (I highlighted the relevant part):

> `object.__str__(self)`
>
> Called by **str(object)** and the built-in functions format() and print() to compute the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of an object. The return value must be a string object.
>
> This method differs from `object.__repr__()` in that there is no expectation that `__str__()` return a valid Python expression: a more convenient or concise representation can be used.
>
> The default implementation defined by the built-in type object calls `object.__repr__()`.

So `your_instance.__str__` is generally called when you do `str(your_instance)`.

---

Longer answer: With "Special Methods" (the methods with two leading underscores and two trailing underscores) there is an exception because these are looked up on the class, not the instance. So `str(a)` is actually `type(a).__str__(a)` and not `a.__str__()`. But in most cases these are the same, because one rarely overrides methods of the class on the instance. Especially not special methods.

See also the [relevant documentation on "Special method lookup"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup):

> For custom classes, **implicit invocations** of special methods are only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an **object’s type**, not in the **object’s instance dictionary**.

So like @zzh1996 pointed out in the comments the following code will use the method defined on the class even though the instance has a custom callable `__str__` attribute:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...         return 'a'
>>> instance = A()
>>> instance.__str__ = lambda: 'b'
>>> str(instance)
'a'
>>> instance.__str__()
'b'
```

Comment: this is wrong!
```
In [21]: class A:
    ...:     def __str__(self):
    ...:         return 'a'
    ...:
    ...:

In [22]: a=A()

In [23]: def f():
    ...:     return 'b'
    ...:

In [24]: a.__str__=f

In [25]: str(a)
Out[25]: 'a'
```

Comment: @zzh1996 Yes, special methods are looked up on the class, not the instance. However I thought that would distract from the actual question which asked if "`str()` function call `__str__()` function of a class?" (which is the case) but `str(a)` is not always equivalent to `a.__str__()` but to `type(a).__str__(a)`. But I added further clarification on that point.

Comment: Note that if the class (or its parents) doesn't define `.__str__` then `.__repr__` will be called. The latter always exists because it's inherited from `object`, unless it's overridden by the class (or a parent).

Comment: Yeah that's correct. It is also mentioned in the docs i copied: "The default implementation defined by the built-in type object calls object.__repr__().". Do you that needs to be emphasised?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does. Take a look at the following example:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self, a):
...         self.a = a
...     def __str__(self):
...         print "Inside __str__"
...         return self.a
...
>>>
>>> a = A('obj1')
>>> a
<__main__.A instance at 0x0000000002605548>
>>>
>>> a.__str__()
Inside __str__
'obj1'
>>>
>>> str(a)
Inside __str__
'obj1'
```

And, from [`__str__()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__), we have:

> `object.__str__(self)`
>
> Called by `str(object)` and the built-in functions
> `format()` and `print()` to compute the “informal” or nicely printable
> string representation of an object. The return value must be a string
> object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but also on print. See docs
[https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**str**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)