# Why str(number) why not number.str() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

why we use str() method in "str(number)" format to convert a number to a string why not to use "number.str()" format, what is the difference between the both, what is difference between methods and attributes

Comment: Have you looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168899/does-python-str-function-call-str-function-of-a-class)?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, there is a standard method `obj.__str__()` that is called when you try to convert an object to a string. When you call `str(number)` what it really does is calling the underlying `__str__` method on the number obj.

`__str__` is a magic method, and it is not a good practice to call them explicitly. Also using `str(obj)` is shorter than `obj.__str__()` and `str(obj)` is standard way of converting an object to string in python.

Regarding `number.str()`, there is no such method in python basic number types at the moment, so cannot really elaborate on the differences