# Getting \n1 \n2 outputs after conversion

Tags: python, dataframe

I am struggling to understand why am I getting `\n1` and `\n2` outputs after converting `int64` to `str`.

From year 2014 to `0 2014\n1 2015\n2 2015\n3 2016`.

This is what I did: `df.Year = str(df.Year)`

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Close-up:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help to perform what was intended (convert a column to a specific type) [Change column type in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-column-type-in-pandas). As regards to why this is happening, lets take an example

```
table.csv
Year
2010
2011
2012
```

lets consider this snippet

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv("table.csv")
print(str(df.Year))
```

The output produced is

```
0    2010
1    2011
2    2012
Name: Year, dtype: int64
```

As this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) clearly mentions, attribute access against a dataframe returns a series object. And when you call str against a series, it basically calls Series.**str** ([Does python `str()` function call `__str__()` function of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168899/does-python-str-function-call-str-function-of-a-class)) and therefore after doing the operation mentioned in the question, you store the result of Series.**str** in every row of the column Year.
As mentioned in the beginning of this post, you can refer to the SO link, it is pretty self explanatory. However, if you want a code sample, please comment.

**Code Snippet**

Here is one of the ways to convert a column to integer type(inspired from the SO link shared above)

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv("table.csv")
df.Year = df.Year.astype(str)
print(type(df.Year[0])) #Prints <class 'str'>
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Extremely helpful for my journey to understand basics and i dont mind having a code sample if it is not too troublesome.

Comment: @Icemilo thank you choosing the post as the answer. Its my pleasure. As you requested, I have included a code sample inspired from a linked SO post. Regards

Answer (score 6):

When you’re using `str(do.Year)` you get a string representation of all the rows, not a Series with each row as a string.
To convert the rows to strings, you need to use `df.Year = df.Year.astype(str)`