# error in returning __str__ from superclass

Tags: python, oop, superclass

I'm getting an inaccurate output for my code. When it calls

```
super().__str__()
```

the output was

```
<__main__.Trip object at 0x00000251D30D5A30>
```

The output should be

```
Driver Id: 1 Name: John Contact: 82121355
```

---

```
from datetime import datetime

class Driver:
    _nextId = 1
    def __init__(self,name,contact):
        self._name = name
        self._contact = contact
        self._driverId = Driver._nextId
        Driver._nextId += 1

    @property
    def driverId(self):
        return self._driverId
    @property 
    def name(self):
        return self._name
    @property
    def contact(self):
        return self._contact
    @contact.setter
    def contact(self, newContact):
        self._contact = newContact

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Driver Id: {self._driverId} Name: {self._name} Contact: {self._contact}'

class Trip:
    def __init__(self,tripDate,startPoint,destination,distance,driver):
        self._tripDate = tripDate
        self._startPoint = startPoint
        self._destination = destination
        self._distance = distance
        self._driver = driver

    @property
    def tripDate(self):
        return self._tripDate
    @property
    def destination(self):
        return self._destination
    @property
    def driver(self):
        return self._driver
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self._tripDate}, From: {self._startPoint} To: {self._destination}\n Distance: {self._distance}km' + super().__str__()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d1 = Driver('John','82121355')
    t1 = Trip(datetime(2021,5,30,17,45),'Empire State Building','Rockerfeller Centre','2.25',d1)
    print(t1)
```

Comment: There is no superclass, because Trip is not a subclass or inherited from Driver, so `super()` will not work. Your `Trip` class has a `self._driver`, so that's what you should use: `str(self._driver)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your `Trip`'s code:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'...' + super().__str__()
```

is that `Trip` is *not* a subclass of `Driver` nor does it inherit anything from `Driver`. The `super` call will *not* call `Driver`'s `__str__` method, but the default/built-in [`object.__str__(self)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) for all Python classes:

```
>>> class XYZ: pass
... 
>>> obj1 = XYZ()
>>> print(obj1)
<__main__.XYZ object at 0x10e28b040>
```

The `super()` only works if your class is a subclass of another:

```
>>> class Animal:
...   def __str__(self):
...     return 'Animal __str__'
... 

>>> class Dog(Animal):
...   def __str__(self):
...     return f'{super().__str__()} + Dog __str__'
... 

>>> d = Dog()
>>> print(d)
Animal __str__ + Dog __str__
```

I don't know why you expect `Trip`'s superclass to be `Driver`, because trips are not drivers, rather a `Trip` involves a `Driver`, so your current implementation where you instantiate a trip with a driver makes sense.

The only thing you need to change is to replace `super()` with `self._driver` which is an instance of `Driver` that you pass to `Trip`.

```
# super().__str__() --> self._driver.__str__()

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self._tripDate}, From: {self._startPoint} To: {self._destination}\n Distance: {self._distance}km' + self._driver.__str__()
```

```
2021-05-30 17:45:00, From: Empire State Building To: Rockerfeller Centre
 Distance: 2.25kmDriver Id: 1 Name: John Contact: 82121355
```

or more simply:

```
# super().__str__() --> str(self._driver)
# And put it inside the f-string

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self._tripDate}, From: {self._startPoint} To: {self._destination}\n Distance: {self._distance}km {str(self._driver)}'
```

```
2021-05-30 17:45:00, From: Empire State Building To: Rockerfeller Centre
 Distance: 2.25km Driver Id: 1 Name: John Contact: 82121355
```

since Python's [`str(obj)` calls that object's `__str__` method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41168899/2745495).