# Is there a difference between str() function and class str in Python

Tags: python, string, function, class

The Python Language Reference 3.11.1 mentions a str() function as:

> Some operations are supported by several object types; in particular, practically all objects can be compared for equality, tested for truth value, and converted to a string (with the repr() function or the slightly different str() function).

How is this different from the class str? Or, when I write

```
str()
```

What is called? The function or the class?

Comment: This might be of interest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168899)

Comment: Thé documentation is very clear, it starts with "class str(object='')". So yes, it's a class, and I guess that it's called the str 'function' in some places in order not to sound overly complicated. After all, it's callable, and most of the time it doesn't make any difference...

Comment: @ThierryLathuille calling it callable might be irritating because usually that term refers to classes implementing `__call__()` whose *instances* are callable. Classes themselves can always be called, as that is the language's way of instantiating them by invoking their constructor.

Comment: @user2390182 There **isn't anything different** about this case. Classes **are** instances of `type`, which **does** implement `__call__`. Calling the class goes through that `type.__call__` logic first, which redirects to `object.__new__`, which invokes built-in machinery, which **only then** (normally) calls `__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of `help(str)`:

```
class str(object)
 |  str(object='') -> str
 |  str(bytes_or_buffer[, encoding[, errors]]) -> str
 |  
 |  Create a new string object from the given object. [...]
 |  Otherwise, returns the result of object.__str__() (if defined)
 |  or repr(object).
```

So, in short: `str(obj)` calls the constructor of the `str` class. What you refer to as the `str` *function* is exactly that: the class' constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "`str()` function`. This part of the documentation is deliberately inaccurate in order to explain things more simply.

In Python, [classes](/questions/48461989) are [callable](/questions/111234), and normally calling them is the way to create an instance of the class. This does **more than** the `__init__` method in the class: it's the part that will interface with Python's behind-the-scenes stuff in order to actually allocate memory for the object, set it up for reference-counting, identify what class it's an instance of, etc. etc.

`str` is the class of strings. Calling `str` creates a string. The documentation calls this a "function" because it looks like one. Similarly for other types, such as `int` and - well - `type` (the class *that classes* are instances of (by default), *including itself*).