# Why can an atribute have a .__str__()?

Tags: python

I was coding a class and a teammate did a peculiar thing:

```
class Dog:

    def __init__(self, hunger, size, cute):
        self.__hunger = hunger
        self.__size = size
        self.__cute = cute

    def __str__(self):
        data_1 = self.__hunger.__str__() # Why is this allowed?
        data_2 = self.__size.__str__()
        data_3 = self.__cute.__str__()
        return f"The dog is {data_1} and {data_2} but is also {data_3}"

a = Dog(20, 120, True)
print(a)
```

He assigned an attribute with .__ str __(). Instead of just:

```
    def __str__(self):
        data_1 = str(self.__hunger)
        data_2 = str(self.__size)
        data_3 = str(self.__cute)
        return f"The dog is {data_1} and {data_2} but is also {data_3}"
```

Why is .__ str __ allowed? and in what does it differ from the "normal" approach of just using str()?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be allowed?

Comment: I would recommend you to watch a tutorial about `magic method` in python

Comment: As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41168971/12575557) explains both options are not exactly the same.

Comment: Just to say that actually the explicit conversion to `str` - one way or the other is redundant, because f-string will do that for you in any case.

Comment: And to address the question in the title - _Why can an atribute have a .__str__()?_ - in python everything is object, so why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str(x)` very simply calls `x.__str__()`.

So, the usages are the same.

The recommended practice is to use `str(x)`, however.

Very rarely is it correct to directly invoke the  special dunder  ( `__xxx__` )  functions.